# Redirect pstore to a file

Tags: linux-kernel, serial-console

PSTORE description says

> pstore is an oops/panic logger that writes its logs to a block device and non-block device

I configured my kernel (embedded system) to store console output to pstore too.

Now what I want is to make pstore store its output to a file on disk.
Is it possible somehow?

Comment: Hm you usually need a panic dump to a raw block device or via serial console exactly when you can't trust filesystems to work correctly. Does this really make sense or are you just trying to write normal kernel logs to a file?

Comment: What I want to do is to have FULL(!) copy of the serial console output in a file. When my embedded system in the field has a problem, I will be able to investigate it.
With the old version of Linux 2.6.31 I had used the rpld driver/patch which did exactly this. But the developer abandoned it many years ago. Before I jumped into porting it to latest version of Linux, I found this pstore. It has option to dump ALL console output to pstore too. So, I wanted to try to utilize it.

Comment: Sorry, the driver name is ttyrpld.